# leastsq trouble passing parameters Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares, bspline, function-fitting

I am trying to fit the following function: Detrended SNR [image]into my data. C1, C2 and h are the parameters I need to obtain from the leastsq's method. C1 and C2 are simple but the problem is that my h(t) is in reality: [image: Function based on B-Splines]. What I want to obtain are the coefficients hj inside that function (in my case there are 35 different hj's ). This function is the sum of different basis B-Splines each one weighted different and the number of coefficients is equal to the number of knots of the B-Spline. As I want to obtain C1, C2 and h1..35 I do the following:

```
funcLine = lambda tpl, eix_x: (tpl[0]*np.sin((4*math.pi*np.sum(bsplines_evaluades * np.transpose([tpl[2],tpl[3],tpl[4],tpl[5],tpl[6],tpl[7],tpl[8],tpl[9],tpl[10],tpl[11],tpl[12],tpl[13],tpl[14],tpl[15],tpl[16],tpl[17],tpl[18],tpl[19],tpl[20],tpl[21],tpl[22],tpl[23],tpl[24],tpl[25],tpl[26],tpl[27],tpl[28],tpl[29],tpl[30],tpl[31],tpl[32],tpl[33],tpl[34],tpl[35],tpl[36],tpl[37]]) , axis=0))*eix_x/lambda1) + tpl[1]*np.cos((4*math.pi*np.sum(bsplines_evaluades * np.transpose([tpl[2],tpl[3],tpl[4],tpl[5],tpl[6],tpl[7],tpl[8],tpl[9],tpl[10],tpl[11],tpl[12],tpl[13],tpl[14],tpl[15],tpl[16],tpl[17],tpl[18],tpl[19],tpl[20],tpl[21],tpl[22],tpl[23],tpl[24],tpl[25],tpl[26],tpl[27],tpl[28],tpl[29],tpl[30],tpl[31],tpl[32],tpl[33],tpl[34],tpl[35],tpl[36],tpl[37]]) , axis=0))*eix_x/lambda1))*np.exp(-4*np.power(k, 2)*lambda_big*np.power(eix_x, 2))
func = funcLine
ErrorFunc = lambda tpl, eix_x, ydata: np.power(func(tpl, eix_x) - ydata,2)
tplFinal1, success = leastsq(ErrorFunc, [2, -2, 8.2*np.ones(35)], args=(eix_x, ydata))
```

tpl(0)=C1, tpl(1)=C2 and tpl(2..35)=my coefficients. bsplines_evaluades is a matrix [35,86000] where each row is the temporal function of each basis b-spline so I weight each row with its individual coefficient, 86000 is the length of eix_x. ydata(eix_x) is the function I want to aproximate. lambda1= 0.1903 ; lambda_big= 2; k=2*pi/lambda1. The output is the same initial parameters which is not logic.
Can anyone help me? I have tried with curvefit too but it does not work.
Data is in : http://www.filedropper.com/data_5>http://www.filedropper.com/download_button.png width=127 height=145 border=0/>
 http://www.filedropper.com >online backup storage

**EDIT**
The code right now is:

```
lambda1 = 0.1903
k = 2 * math.pi / lambda1
lambda_big = 2
def funcLine(tpl, eix_x):
    C1, C2, h = tpl[0], tpl(1), tpl[2:]
    hsum = np.sum(bsplines_evaluades * h, axis=1)  # weight each
    theta = 4 * np.pi * np.array(hsum) * np.array(eix_x) / lambda1
    return (C1*np.sin(theta)+C2*np.cos(theta))*np.exp(-4*lambda_big*(k*eix_x)**2)  # lambda_big = 2
if len(eix_x) != 0:
    ErrorFunc = lambda tpl, eix_x, ydata: funcLine(tpl, eix_x) - ydata
    param_values = 7.5 * np.ones(37)
    param_values[0] = 2
    param_values(1) = -2
    tplFinal2, success = leastsq(ErrorFunc, param_values, args=(eix_x, ydata))
```

The problem is that the output parameters don't change with respect the initial ones. Data (x_axis,ydata,bsplines_evaluades):
gist.github.com/hect1995/dcd36a4237fe57791d996bd70e7a9fc7 gist.github.com/hect1995/39ae4768ebb32c27f1ddea97e24d96af gist.github.com/hect1995/bddd02de567f8fcbedc752371b47ff71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always helpful (to yourself as well as us) to provide a readable example that is complete enough to be runnable.  Your example with `lambda`s and very long line is definitely not readable, making it very easy for you to miss simple mistakes. One of the points of using Python is to make code easier to read.

It is fine to have spline coefficients as fit variables, but you want to have the np.ndarray of variables to be exactly 1-dimensional.   So your parameter array should be

```
param_values = 8.2 * np.ones(37)
param_values[0] = 2
param_values[1] = -2.
result_params, success = leastsq(errorFunc, param_values, ....)
```

It should be fine to use curve_fit() too.  Beyond that, it's hard to give much help, as you give neither a complete runnable program (leaving lots of terms undefined), nor the output or error messages from running your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, next time I will try to explain better (I am going to do an edit in this post to clarify it). The problem right now is that it does not matter the initial values of the parameters that after the leastsq the output parameters haven't changed. Do you know how can I post the data I have (tables) so people can try it?

Comment: Your code still uses lambda and has many undefined variables (k, lambda1, lambda_big, bsplines_evaluades). It cannot be run by someone else.  You still did not post output or error messages.  For posting data, many people use github gists or other similar services.

Comment: But also, now that I can sort of read your code: if bsplines_evaluades is a an array (as it looks to be), then your fit does NOT depend much on the individual values of 35 of your parameters, but only on the sum they give.  That is, you're not actually using `h`, only `hsum`.  Is that intentional?  It will definitely make the fit result not very sensitive to most of those values.

Comment: Yes, but te sum depends on the different coefficients of h. Each basis spline is centered in a certain point in the x axis (temporal) so weighting the different splines independently I can model my sum function in the temporal axis

Comment: The result of the fit does not depend on the individual components of your 'h', only on their (weighted) sum.  This fit has 3 independent parameters, your 'C1', 'C2', and 'hsum'.    You have 34 extra values that do not alter the fit.   That will definitely confuse leastsq().

Comment: And what can I do if I want to obtain the 34 parameters of the knots (h's) as my returning values? I add the links to the data (lambda and all the other constants you were asking for are in the original post) https://gist.github.com/hect1995/dcd36a4237fe57791d996bd70e7a9fc7  https://gist.github.com/hect1995/39ae4768ebb32c27f1ddea97e24d96af https://gist.github.com/hect1995/07efbe1291b1fef17058abbdfdf954bf

Comment: Well, your fit residual does not depend on the individual values of `h`, only only the weighted sum.   So that sum is all the fit is really going to be able to tell you.  You might have other information about the components of `h`, but this fit residual function does not capture that.  Also, it sure looks like most (by far) of your values for `bsplines_evaluades` are zero, which would make your `hsum` not very sensitive to changing values of `h` anyway.

Comment: They are zero because basis splines that are centered in a point, have a little range of action. http://www.brnt.eu/phd/ucbs-basis.png      Do you know where I can find how to modify the h's inside hsum?

Comment: Ah, your spline coefficients *might* be possible to fit (bsplines_evaluades is 2D!).  I think the main problem you see is that the exponential decay term is just always giving zero, and that your '(-4*lambda_big*(k*eix_x)**2) is too large by a factor of several thousand.

Answer (score 0):

Several things could be wrong here: I'm not sure you're indexing your `tpl` array correctly (if it has 37 entries, the indexes should be `0:36`). And your errorFunc should probably return the residual rather than the square residual.

Finally, I think your h-sum may be incorrect: you want to sum over the $N$ axis but not the $x$ axis, right?

You might tidy up your code as follows and see if it helps (without some data it's difficult to test for myself):

```
def funcLine(tpl, eix_x):
    C1, C2, h = tpl[0], tpl[1], tpl[2:]
    hsum = np.sum(bsplines_evaluades * h, axis=1)
    theta = 4 * np.pi * hsum * eix_x / lambda1
    return (C1 * np.sin(theta) + C2 * np.cos(theta)) * np.exp(-4  *lambda_big *
                 (k * eix_x)**2)

errorFunc = lambda tpl, eix_x, ydata: funcLine(tpl, eix_x) - ydata
tplFinal2, success = leastsq(errorFunc, [2, -2, 8.2*np.ones(35)],
                             args=(eix_x, ydata))
```

Comment: You are right about 0:36. I forgot to change it in my question. Once I have all my basis splines and each one has been multiplied by it weight I want to add all the basis contributions for each time i order to have an array of 86000. I will try what you say but it will be difficult to provide data as it weights a lot, but I will try

Comment: Data:gist.github.com/hect1995/dcd36a4237fe57791d996bd70e7a9fc7 gist.github.com/hect1995/39ae4768ebb32c27f1ddea97e24d96af gist.github.com/hect1995/bddd02de567f8fcbedc752371b47ff71